# Process in a polling state?

Tags: linux, process

Given a process ID, how can I tell if that process is currently blocked in a polling state?  i.e. it has called poll() with a negative timeout, and is waiting for input to become ready.

Comment: What do you mean by "polling state"? Polling usually does not involve blocking.

Comment: @Mat edited the question to clarify (hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UNIX-like systems the command line utility 'ps' provides this information. There are many flavors of ps depending on the OS, so read the man page.

On a BSD-like system (mac):

```
ps -eo pid,user,cpu,state,comm

  PID USER     CPU STAT COMM
    1 root       0 Ss   /sbin/launchd
   15 root       0 Ss   /usr/libexec/kextd
90710 root       0 R+   ps
83804 joe        0 Ss   /bin/bash
89631 joe        0 S+   ssh
```

where STAT is the process state. S means interruptible sleep. s (lower case) means session leader. '+' means it's in the foreground process group. R means running, or runnable (on run queue). There are many more possible states.

Comment: On Linux it seems that ps -o state gives you the state information; thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the Linux tag on the question, or I would have shown a linux example.